# is this the proper use of 'in' in a conditional statement?

Tags: python

This is an overly simplified version of the problem that I'm working on. It's crude and basic but I just started out with python and wanna make sure that I have my basics straightened out.
I can't seem to get the desired output with this. For ex: When the list generated by a() contains '2', when I call out b() it does not give me the required value of y, which in this case should be 2.

```
from random import choice, sample

def a():
    a = sample(range(0,5),2)
    a.append(1)
    return a 

def b():
    if 3 in a():
        y = 1
    elif 2 in a():
        y = 2
    else:
        pass
    return y

print a()
print b()
```

Comment: Can you please make an edit to your question and describe what the desired output is?

Comment: You test if 3 and 2 belong in two different samples in `b()`, is this really what you mean?

Comment: I want the b() function to give me '1' if the list in a()  contains 3 and '2' if it contains 2. I want this to run in the same list.

Comment: Then don't call `a()` twice. Do `my_sample = a()`, then `if 3 in my_sample:  ...  elif 2 in my_sample: ... `

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, ah Thank you soo much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your program, most notably, you are calling `a` within `b`, which I  don't think you want to do. Within `b`, you are regenerating a list of new random values and then checking the contents of this list.

Also, you should not use `pass` in your `else` statement because you could imagine the possibility where `y` is never defined, and therefore you will fail to return something. I would suggest the following:

```
from random import choice, sample

def a():
    a = sample(range(0,5),2)
    a.append(1)
    return a 

def b(a):
    if 3 in a:
        return 1
    elif 2 in a:
        return 2
    else:
        return

a_output = a()
print a_output
print b(a_output)
```

However, this is an odd way to check the contents of a list. Without knowing the purpose of your program, it is difficult to make a recommendation for an alternative way to write a more pythonic function.